# В xcode ImageView закрывает кнопки

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Есть проект в Xcode. При создании в StoryBoard ViewController, когда задаем imageView и на нем размещаем кнопки, то они оказываются под imageView. Где есть настройка чтобы кнопки были по слою сверху imageView?

Answer (score 2):

Проверьте иерархию елементов у контроллера, должно быть что-то такое

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и еще проблема может быть в том что вы добавили кнопки как сабвью для imageView а они должны быть отдельно друг от друга

Answer (score 1):

Добавлять `subview` для `UIImageView` не следует, `UIImageView` не предназначен для этого.

В вашем случае нужно создать `UIView` и в него вставить `button` и `imageView` сохраняя необходимую иерархию.